# Отладка в Node.js

Tags: node.js

Есть ли нормальное встроенное средство отладки в Node.js, проблема в том что есть самописный NodeJS сервак который генерит запросы в LDAP . и переодически после серии запросов он "залипает". хотелось бы понять что он там делает и на что спотыкается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, можно к нему из хрома подключиться и дебажить скрипт.

http://learn.javascript.ru/nodejs-screencast
Видео 18: https://youtu.be/COHIRHitRdc

Comment: неработает, немогу поставить node-inpect, вываливает ошибку msb3428, просит поставить либо Net Framework SDK 2.0 , поставил непомогло, 2-й вариант ставить Visual C++. этого я делать точно небуду, загаживать так машину я не собираюсь, в прошлый раз замучался вычищать весь тот мусор что VCS притащил с собой, вобщем нужен другой вариант

Comment: не с первого раза с кучей ошибок и тоько после удаления пакета mongodb (и что он к нему привязался) он таки заработал, хотя чую я что в проблема в глубинах ноды и отладка тут может не помочь

Answer (score 0):

Можете воспользоваться IDE, которые поддерживают отладку nodejs: WebStorm, Visual Studio 2013/2015 (с помощью дополнительного расширения).
Такие продвинутые редакторы как Visual Studio Code и Atom (при помощи плагина) тоже поддерживают отладку nodejs.

По поводу Visual C++. Компилятор С++, а также Python вам, возможно, придётся установить. Не сейчас, так позже. Некоторые модули используют native-код, реализация которого как раз написана на том же C++.

Comment: ну питон уже стоит, он весит немного, а плюсовые модули которые не работают с чистым node я просто не использую, потому что они ломают переносимость, а без этого Node теряет все свои плюсы